# git grep is missing matches

Tags: git, grep

To find the classes having a private constructor I would like to use

```
git grep -lzP 'class\s+(\w++)[\s\S]*private\s+\1'
```

But it finds no result, however with the find command it finds

```
find */src/main/java -type f -exec grep -lzP 'class\s+(\w++)[\s\S]*private\s+\1' {} +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `git help grep`:

```
       -z, --null
           Output \0 instead of the character that normally follows a file name.
```

It only says that ASCII NUL will be added to output filenames. So, I don't think this is equivalent to `grep -z` which treats "input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte".

You can use `grep -r` instead of `find+grep`. I'd also recommend [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) for better performance.

Comment: thank you, indeed i though the options of git grep may not be the same as grep, i didn't knew ripgrep and not installed by default, otherwise i find, `find` more flexible than `grep -r`, and with the `+` at the end it spaws minimal number of processes (like xargs)